# JAVA: Trying to change an object without making a new object

Tags: java, object, point

I am working with a Point object that has an x and y component, Point(double x, double y). I want to write a function that changes the values of the x and y component without having a 
new Point p = ...
For Example, this is my current version:

```
public class Point{
private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    }

    public Point movePoint(double dx, double dy) {
        return new Point(this.x + dx, this.y + dy);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like movePoint() without making a new Point?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mutable value objects are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly.  Just change your code to return a reference to `this` as such:

```
public Point movePoint(double dx, double dy) {
    this.x += dx;
    this.y += dy;
    return this;
}
```

Also note that Java has a built in class for storing double precision points in its [`java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try this:

```
public class Point{
private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point movePoint(double dx, double dy) {
        this.x += dx;
        this.y += dy;
        return this;
    }
}
```